# Not able to make a rounded avatar

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, avatar

I'm trying to do a rounded avatar in the header of a side-menu on ionic2 framework.

This is my code

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar >
     <!-- <ion-title>Options</ion-title>-->
     <span><ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="./assets/img/defAvatar.png">
      </ion-avatar> <h1>User</h1></span>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

When y launch this code to ionic serve --lab this is the result

[image]

What would be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `ion-item`

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar >
     <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-left>
        <img src="./assets/img/defAvatar.png">
       </ion-avatar> <h1>User</h1>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
```

Check [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#avatar-list)